# Слово "может", идущее за словом "нужно". Нет ли здесь коллизии смыслов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, смысл

> Дату и время указывай с оглядкой на стандарт ISO 8601: «от большего к меньшему» и используя 24-часовой формат времени. **Год, когда это нужно для краткости, может быть указан в двузначном виде.**

Этот фрагмент взят из технического руководства, над которым я сейчас работаю.

Мне не нравится, что придаточное предложение начинается со слова "может", за счёт чего имея характер **рекомендации** (= **необязательности**), в то время как предшествующее ему главное предложение содержит слово "нужно", за счёт чего указывая на **необходимость** последующих действий.

Ещё можно так:

> Год, когда это нужно для краткости, указывай в двузначном виде.

Так противоречия нет, но есть другая проблема: мы как бы подталкиваем к использованию двузначного года, в то время как такая форма его записи в большинстве случаев нежелательна.

Прав ли я, что первый вариант звучит нечётко? Как бы вы сформулировали предложение из примера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь нет противоречия.

Это условное предложение.

«Когда» вводит условие: если нужно, то можно поступить так.

Следовательно: если не нужно, то можно и не поступать так. Никакой обязательности нет.

> **КОГДА́**, нареч. и союз.
>  II. союз.
> 2. условный. Употребляется (часто с частицей „бы“) в начале условного предложения; **соответствует по значению союзу если** (в 1 знач.).
> *Майор Ковалев был не прочь и жениться, но только в таком случае, когда
> за невестою случится двести тысяч капиталу.* Гоголь, Нос. *Все это было
> бы смешно, Когда бы не было так грустно.* Лермонтов, А. О. Смирновой.
> *Природа-мать! когда б таких людей Ты иногда не посылала миру, Заглохла
> б нива жизни.* Н. Некрасов, Памяти Добролюбова. *— Когда ясна цель,
> когда мы организованны и единодушны, для нас нет невыполнимых задач.*
> Ажаев, Далеко от Москвы… [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Если нужно доехать до центра города, то можно сесть на трамвай, или можно поехать на такси, или можно, в крайнем случае, пойти пешком и т. п.

«Когда нужно» не говорит об обязательности, а просто указывает на условие, при возникновении которого можно найти вот такой выход.

«Может» тут от «мочь».

> **МОЧЬ** 1, могу́, мо́жешь, мо́гут; прош. мог, -ла́, -ло́; прич. наст.
> могу́щий; несов.
>
> 1. (сов. смочь) обычно с неопр. Быть в состоянии, в силах что-л. делать. *Бопре в смятении хотел было привстать и не мог: несчастный
>    француз был мертво пьян.* Пушкин, Капитанская дочка. *Старшина хочет
>    что-то сказать, но не может.* Чехов, Скорая помощь. *Ты по стране идешь.
>    И нет такой преграды, Чтобы тебя остановить могла.* Исаковский, Ты по
>    стране идешь. || **Иметь возможность что-л. делать.** *Очки он не мог
>    снять: он был слишком близорук. Л. Толстой, Два спутника.* || (сов.
>    нет). *Быть способным, уметь что-л. делать. Ты знаешь, я владеть
>    стрелою Могу.* Лермонтов, Измаил-Бей. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Другими словами:

*«Год, **когда** это нужно для краткости, **может** быть указан в двузначном виде».*

*«Год, **если** это [вам] нужно для краткости, **есть возможность** [в приложении или в устройстве] указать в двузначном виде».*

Тут ничто ничему не противоречит.

*Если вам нужно подняться на 20-й этаж, есть возможность поехать на лифте или пойти по лестнице.*

***Когда** вам нужно подняться на 20-й этаж, **можно** поехать на лифте или пойти по лестнице.*

Но ведь вас никто не заставляет подниматься туда.

*Если вам это нужно, то можно сесть в лифт или пойти по лестнице*, а если не нужно, то и нет смысла говорить о том, какие есть возможности — условие, заданное «если», не выполнено.

Никакого противоречия между «нужно» и «можно» нет.

Возможно, у вас сложилось такое впечатление из-за похожего слова «можно»:

> **МО́ЖНО**, безл. в знач. сказ.
>
> 1. с неопр. Есть условия, возможности для осуществления чего-л. [Ольга:] *Сегодня тепло, можно окна держать настежь.* Чехов, Три сестры.
>    *В молочной топилась железная печка, и можно было согреться.* Катаев,
>    Отче наш.
> 2. Разрешается, позволительно. *[Ирина:] Нет, пожалуйста, уходите, Василий Васильич.* Сюда нельзя. *[Соленый:] Почему же это барону можно,
>    а мне нельзя?* Чехов, Три сестры. *Иван Матвеевич потянул на себя дверь
>    директорского кабинета, она подалась. — К вам можно? — Войдите.*
>    Игишев, Шахтеры. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Например:

*«Ему нужно идти на работу»* и *«Ему можно идти на работу»* — имеет разный смысл: 
*«Ему необходимо идти на работу»* и *«Ему разрешено (но не факт, что необходимо) идти на работу».*

*«**Нужно** выйти на свежий воздух»* и *«Хорошая погода, **можно** выйти на свежий воздух»* — имеет разный смысл:
*«**Необходимо** выйти на свежий воздух»* и *«Хорошая погода, **есть возможность (условия)** выйти на свежий воздух (хотя, может, особой необходимости и нет)».*

Answer (score 3):

Ваши сомнения и выведение смыслов основываются на предположении, что (цитирую) *придаточное предложение начинается со слова "может"*. На самом деле **придаточное** предложение здесь находится **внутри главного** (это оно обособлено запятыми) и выражает условие (когда, в каком случае?), при котором допускается (словами "может быть указан") упрощенный способ указания года. Возможно, более наглядным и убедительным по смыслу вам покажется вариант *этого же* предложения с **придаточным после главного**:

> Год может быть указан в двузначном виде, когда это нужно для
> краткости.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не простой, на логическое мышление.

Как известно, дыма без огня не бывает. Сразу заметил, что здесь что-то не то. Вы правы. Здесь есть коллизия, хотя по общему звучанию может показаться, что всё в порядке. Как она вычисляется? Да математическим путём.

Слово "это" ссылается на "указан в двузначном виде". Подставим это значение. Получается такой смысл:
*Год, когда его нужно указать в двузначном виде для краткости, может быть указан...*
Получается такая схема:
*Если нужно указать, можно указать.* || Как-то это не логично. Логичнее:
*Если нужно указать, укажи.* || Но так не очень вежливо.

Здесь нет ситуации с вариантами, о которых говорит Eagle:
*Если нужна краткость, можно использовать сокращения, можно употребить аббревиатуру, можно заменить на что-то покороче.*

Как избежать данной коллизии? Не использовать слово "это":
*Год, когда нужна краткость, может быть указан в двузначном виде.*

Но сама такая структура не удачна. Она больше к разговорному стилю относится. Хороший вариант для замены:
*Для краткости год можно указать в двузначном виде.*

Comment: Удачный вариант для замены!  Нужный смысл четко обозначен,  а форма  при этом предельно краткая и экономная.

Answer (score 1):

«Дату и время указывай с оглядкой на стандарт ISO 8601: «от большего к меньшему» и используя 24-часовой формат времени. Год, когда это нужно для краткости, может быть указан в двузначном виде.»
Эта фраза ближе к авторскому (живому), чем к техническому тексту.
В первом предложении имеется снисходительно - отеческое «указывай», вместо нейтрального «следует указывать».
Есть сомнение, что авторское «с оглядкой» будет понято читателем текста как призыв к соблюдению требований стандарта во всех (без исключения) случаях. Очевидным излишеством будет, например, вариант «с опаской хоть на йоту нарушить требования», хотя он немного точнее.
Оттенки смысла первого предложения отражаются на прочтении второго. Так оборот «может быть указан» невольно понимаешь как дозволение самого автора «можешь указать», но не допущение, оговоренное стандартом.

Технический текст видится примерно так:
"Дату и время следует указывать в соответствии с (требованиями стандарта) ISO 8601. Предпочтение должно отдаваться полному представлению даты в расширенном формате (YYY-MM-DD) и полному представлению времени в 24-часовом формате (hh:mm:ss).
Стандартом допускается сокращенное представление календарной даты,  когда год указывают двузначным числом".

Comment: Я проголосовал, но не полностью согласен. Хотя конструкция со словом "следует" звучит более серьезно, на мой взгляд она лишь загромождает текст. К тому же, это слово может оказаться необходимым в других значениях и корнях; например, "... из чего следует ..." или "и как следствие..."

Comment: В нашем языке совсем не трудно разнообразить слово «следует». Для этой цели можно использовать слова:  полагается, надлежит, необходимо, нужно.        
Нет проблем и в облегчении конструкции «следует указывать». Попробуйте примерить пару вариантов: «дата и время указываются…» или «дата и время обозначаются…».